# Need to call a function and place value back in formula

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have created a Public function called RoundPlus and added it to a module.
Now when I try and call the function from a cell I get #VALUE error and I cannot figure out why.

The desired behavior is to check if values are zero or under 500 then if not, go to ROUNDPLUS function with the sum of result and round it appropriately based on the cases in the ROUNDPLUS FUNCTION and return that value back to the formula

=IF(SUM(F202:F205)=0,0,IF(SUM(F202:F205)<500,500,ROUNDPLUS(SUM(F202:F205),-2)))

Here is the function.. The Roundplus should do the rounds and place the resulting value back in the formula and then the formula place the place in the cell.

```
Public Function RoundPlus(dblValue As Double) As Double

Dim n As Integer

On Error 
GoTo Err_Procedure 

Select Case dblValue 

Case Is < 10001: n = 100 

Case Is < 25001: n = 250 Case Is < 50001: n = 500 

Case Is < 100001: n = 1000 Case Is < 250001: n = 2500 

Case Else: n = 5000 

End Select 

RoundPlus = Round(dblValue / n) * n 

Else RoundPlus = dblValue 

End If

Exit_Procedure: 
Exit Function 
Err_Procedure: errorHandler Err.Number, Err.Description, "calcBasePrem()", Erl 
Resume

Exit_Procedure 

Resume

End Function
```

Comment: Why is there an **end if** when there is no **if** ??

Comment: Hmm, I see that.  I will change it  to END . Does that seem to be the issue? I am concerned as to how to get the value to populate back into ROUNDPLUS in the formula.. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Why are you supplying ***2*** arguments to `ROUNDPLUS()` when the code only allows ***1*** ??

Comment: Do you mean -2 after the ROUNDPLUS?

Comment: ...........yes.....................

Comment: Ok, I am removing the -2.  But I still get the value message

Comment: I am getting a compile error now after removing the if,,- it says   else without If compile error

Comment: Disregard - I figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help!